# Cant Access a site,either from browser, or desktop client

Tags: internet-connection, timeout

I face a really weird problem. Nobody in our office, can access Yammer. Either the [web application](https://www.yammer.com/), or from the desktop app. I use Ubuntu 10.04. I tried checking the router and modem for blocked IPs or ports, but there are no rules set to block access. Yammer says their service is fine, which is verified because I can login to the webapp, and from the desktop client from my home machine. Trying to access the site from my browser, I get this error:

> Error 118 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.

The desktop app says

> Searching for service

What should I do to pinpoint the problem? Where do you think the problem lies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A common cause for such problems is bad DNS entries cached by the router. Check if there are any router settings for turning this off, or a firmware update. It might also help to know which model is the router and its firmware version and where does the modem come in.

This blog could maybe be of help : [Clear DNS Cache on your router](http://ariejan.net/2007/07/07/clear-dns-cache-on-your-router/).

Some routers are known for having DNS problems. If your work computer is set to obtain the DNS server automatically, you could try to verify this hypothesis by setting its DNS servers directly to these of your ISP (or choose among [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) or [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) or [DNS Advantage](http://www.dnsadvantage.com/)).